# Playready encrypted test SMOOTH content with a license URL and token

Tags: smooth-streaming, playready

Is there a test Playreadyready encrypted SMOOTH stream that needs a license URL and token? I had a look into http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/ and got a playready encrypted stream http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/SSWSS720H264PR/SuperSpeedway_720.ism/Manifest .
However, this plays even without a license server URL and token. Had a look into Microsoft Azure media services for encrypting a content, however encryption option is disabled in free version. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too, usually the license server URL is embedded on the Manifest file, when AVPlay doesn't get the URL on the config, it gets the license URL from the manifest and starts playback.